# Use of unassigned out variable though i assign it a default value

Tags: out

```
using System;

namespace Examples
{
   public class HelloWorld
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
      int y=5;
      A(out y);
         }
      public static void A(out int x)
      {
      Console.WriteLine(x);
      x=1;
      }
   } 
}
```

Though i assign a default value to the out variable it still throws an error while trying to write it in console."USE OF UNASSIGNED VARIABLE". Doesn't x and y both point to the same memory location ? Explain please....

Comment: At the time you tried to print x, it had not yet been assigned. You don't assign x until the next line. Swap the order of the two lines.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen- But i have assigned the value of y right ?  Doesn't x and y both point to the same memory location ?

Comment: `y` is not part of the function `A`. Imagine if somebody else does this: `int z; A(out z);`. Now you are reading from `x` before writing to it, and `z` was never assigned. If you declare a parameter as `out` then it is assumed that nobody has given it a value yet. See [Rule 12.1.6(3)4](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/12.1.6.htm): " Within a function member, an output parameter is considered initially unassigned."